# Comparing proportions from the same sample of patients

Tags: survey, proportion, population

The question I have is how to test if two proportions from the same sample of patients are significantly different from each other, indicated by a p-value?

Example: 100 people, 1 has Disease A and 2 have Disease B. Is the occurrence of Disease A more frequent than Disease B, ie. occurrence of Disease A given by 1/100 compared to 2/100 for B?

Keyword is 'same' sample of patients. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Can the same patient have both diseases?

Comment: Since these samples are the same standard inference assuming independent random samples form a given population is violated. What is the inference that you want to make?  Are you wanting to test whether or not the data indicate that the incidence for B is greater than for A in the population that the 100 patients were sampled from?

Comment: @Michael Chernick: yes patient can have both diseases.I do want to test whether or not the data indicate that the incidence for B is greater than for A in the population that the 100 patients were sampled from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking about is a test of dependent (or paired) proportions.  Please see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) on McNemar's test or [this calculator site](http://www.mccallum-layton.co.uk/stats/ZTestForProportionDependentGroup_SampleSize.aspx) (its language isn't the clearest, but it will help you calculate the result you're looking for).

Comment: The problem with McNemar is, however, that it takes into account mutual exclusive cases only, i.e. those persons who has A only and B only. Significance of differences depends only on these figures and does not depends on total sample. For example, you have only total 10 cases "A only" plus "B only". Calculated p will depends on how A differ from B and does not depends that these 10 cases over 30 persons total (who have both A and B or nothing) or over 3000. The p will be the same. This is a problem,

Comment: So whats the solution. I still think that the normal test for proportion, the z test, is usable.